# NHibernate pagination with oracle

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, pagination

As always for pagination, I use

```
var users = session.QueryOver<User>()
                   .Skip(10)
                   .Take(50);
                   .List<User>();
```

but I've noticed that sql query is generated (for oracle db)

```
SELECT
      this_.ID as ID6_1_,
      this_.Name as Name6_1_
FROM
     Users this_
```

without any expressions for pagination. Why? So all `Users` rows will be loaded into the memory and then the pagination fires?

Answer (score 1):

Well, NHiberante of course supports native DB paging. With proper dialect setting - all should work as expected

In case we are using [Oracle12cDialect](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/Oracle12cDialect.cs#L12), there is a code snippet:

```
namespace NHibernate.Dialect
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// A dialect specifically for use with Oracle 10g.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The main difference between this dialect and <see cref="Oracle12cDialect"/>
    /// is the use of "ANSI join syntax" here...
    /// </remarks>
    public class Oracle12cDialect : Oracle10gDialect
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Oracle 12c supports a query statement that provides <c>LIMIT</c>
        /// functionality with an offset.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value><c>false</c></value>
        public override bool UseMaxForLimit
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override SqlString GetLimitString(SqlString querySqlString, SqlString offset, SqlString limit)
        {
            var result = new SqlStringBuilder(querySqlString);

            if (offset != null)
            {
                result.Add(" OFFSET ");
                result.Add(offset).Add(" ROWS");
            }

            if (limit != null)
            {
                result.Add(" FETCH FIRST ").Add(limit).Add(" ROWS ONLY");
            }

            return result.ToSqlString();
        }
    }
}
```

Previous dialects used [Oracle8iDialect](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/Oracle8iDialect.cs#L266) implementation